# How can I get Google Funding Choices to work with PreBid.js

Tags: javascript, ads, prebid.js, fundingchoices

We're using both GFC as our consent platform and client side PreBid along with Google DFP.
The implementation looks correct and most of the time we see the bids appearing correctly along with the consent tokens, however, on some occasions we get the following error message from prebid:

`ERROR: CMP not found. Canceling auction as per consentManagement config. undefined`.

We load both scripts asynchronously, but we do load Google's script first and then `Prebid.js` right after that.

We suspect that Google's implementation doesn't create the `__tcfapi` or `__cmp` objects immediately on the global scope, and that if those are not present, PreBid cancels the auction and doesn't fire the bids.

Did anyone else stumble upon this issue and can verify? Is there a way to prevent this from happening without delaying the page load or the ads? If not, is there a way to register an error handler on prebid?

Comment: May you post how you load the two scripts?

Comment: The first script is funding choices on the head with the initialization all the init code with an async tag. 
We then load gam and prebid async as well after our client side code loads and decides if to render ads.

Comment: I meant the code you use. No code,hard to answer

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. We use fundingchoices which is now integrated into Google AdManager.

Try

```
window.googlefc = window.googlefc || {};
window.googlefc.ccpa = window.googlefc.ccpa || {}
window.googlefc.callbackQueue = window.googlefc.callbackQueue || [];
// wait for consent
googlefc.callbackQueue.push({
  'CONSENT_DATA_READY': () => {
       // do prebidding
   }
});
```

But it seems to be very slow as the Google Publisher Tag (gpt.js) must be loaded which then decides that a FundingChoice/CMP is needed which gets loaded and then after a while the consent is available.

We don't have it production because it is too slow. Does somebody knwo how to speed things up with fundingchoice aka AdManger-GDPR-Messages